# Compare in Python two lists and create a new one that is combinated

Tags: python, list

I have two lists that look like this :

```
a = [{"service" : "yoga", "price": 30}, {"service": "golf", "price" : 40}]
b = ["basketball", "yoga", "soccer", "golf"]
```

I'd like to compare the list and return a combinated one like this :

```
c = [{"service" : "basketball", "price": None}, {"service" : "yoga", "price": 30}, {"service" : "soccer", "price": None},{"service": "golf", "price" : 40}]
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to approach this solution please ?

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: `[{'service': s, 'price': next((t['price'] for t in a if t['service'] == s), None)} for s in b]` would do, though it's somewhat obscure and sub-optimal…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
d = {i['service']: i['price'] for i in a}
print([{'service': i, 'price': d.get(i)} for i in b])
```

Output:

```
[{'service': 'basketball', 'price': None}, {'service': 'yoga', 'price': 30}, {'service': 'soccer', 'price': None}, {'service': 'golf', 'price': 40}]
```